# Windows phone 8.1 httpClient and session cookies

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, session-cookies

Does httpClient store and resend session cookies?

Because using PostAsync I am connecting to (and debugging) a server and after login when I check my status the sessions doesn't exists.

And if it is true, how can I say to HttpClient to use cookies? I have been looking for this question and I am only finding people asking how to manipulate cookies, I only want to mantain session cookies.

Thank you.

The code I use

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage httpResp = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HttpMessageHandlers cookie container:

```
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var cookieContainer = handler.CookieContainer;

            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: But then..., It stores the cookies in the cookieContainer, so there is no way to do it atutomatically?, I mean I have to get the cookies from the container and manage them?

Because if the app is closed that object will lose, so have I to store the cookies in the phone and reload it if the app is closed? I think yes with this way :-(

Comment: Exactly. You can use ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings for example.

Comment: Thank you :-)

Well... now I have to find the best way to store a cookie as string and then reload, (because LocalSettings only admits simple types like numbers, strings or booleans)

Comment: Cookies are strings.  Otherwise: Just put them in a dictionary and serialize it to json.