# Losing Session Values After Calling Web API

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, session-variables

I am trying to consume a Web API from my code behind page and after getting the response from the Web Api, I always lose my Session values.

```
Dim formatter As New JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
    Using client = New HttpClient()
  Dim chkValue =  HttpContext.Current.Session("UserName") // Has a value here
        client.BaseAddress = New Uri(apiAddress)
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync("requestURI", "customObject", "formatter")
        If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                HttpContext.Current.Session("UserName") // Referenced object has value of nothing
        Else

        End If
    End Using
```

This is within a method using Async modifier, not sure if that could lead to something like this.

Comment: You're using 2 different session objects to describe the problem. Are you saying that testing `HttpContext.Current.Session("UserName")` at the LoggedClientName line is where the reference exists vs later in the method where it does not?

Comment: Sorry it should have being the same. Edited now.

Comment: I wouldn't say yours is a direct duplicate, but perhaps the answer to this related question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672598/windows-phone-8-1-httpclient-and-session-cookies

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tried it, but that did not work : (

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [ASP.NET Web API session or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478244/asp-net-web-api-session-or-something): As of the first response, webapi is stateless, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11479021/2298807) explains why.

If you need to store information, you may need store them in a cookie (**not recommended**) or store them in the application cache with a cookie value as the key.

Comment: I am only trying to consume a Web Api. So I don't understand why the session values set in my web forms are lost.